# Javascript equivalent of array_unique in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ecmascript-6, unique-values

I've been looking for a native javascript function which represents the equivalent of **PHP**'s

```
$Fruit_Bowl = array_unique($Fruit_Bowl);
```

I can recreate this myself, using a pair of nested loops:

- the outer loop counts down through the array
- the inner loop checks if the current element is a duplicate of something we've already had

**Working Example:**

```js
let fruitBowl = [
  'apple',
  'apple',
  'apple',
  'apple',
  'apple',
  'banana',
  'banana',
  'cherry',
  'cherry',
  'cherry',
  'damson',
  'elderberry',
  'fig',
  'fig'
];

for (i = (fruitBowl.length - 1); (i + 1) > 0; i--) {
  for (j = (i + 1); j < fruitBowl.length; j++) {
    if (fruitBowl[j] === fruitBowl[i]) {
      fruitBowl.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}

console.log(fruitBowl);
```

But, surely there is something faster, more concise and more elegant than this?

(Perhaps in newer versions of javascript, if not in older ones?)

Comment: I typed in "duplicates" in my URL bar and got the page from my browser history. It's quite common question, so I remember part of the title and it's enough to find it in browser history. You can also find it by using "unique array javascript" in your search engine. [First result in Google for me](https://i.imgur.com/zD7Gfrd.png)

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. I think I typed in variations of: _"javascript equivalent of array_unique in PHP"_ and had no luck despite repeated searches.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] surely there is something faster, more concise and more elegant than this?

Yes, it turns out there is.

I'm less familiar with *collections* in Javascript like `Map` and `Set` but it turns out that `Set` very explicitly represents a special kind of `Array` which may only contain an element once.

Consequently, turning an `array` into a `set` and then back into an `array`:

```
fruitBowl = [... new Set(fruitBowl)];
```

is exactly what I needed.

**Working Example:**

```js
let fruitBowl = [
  'apple',
  'apple',
  'apple',
  'apple',
  'apple',
  'banana',
  'banana',
  'cherry',
  'cherry',
  'cherry',
  'damson',
  'elderberry',
  'fig',
  'fig'
];

fruitBowl = [... new Set(fruitBowl)];

console.log(fruitBowl);
```

Comment: "*it turns out that Set very explicitly represents a special kind of Array which may only contain an element once*" [that's not a JS thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type))

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for the heads up. It's good to learn that `Sets` are not exclusively a JS thing but I should mention that I've never encountered `Sets` in PHP, HTML, CSS, SVG, JSON etc.

Comment: HTML is a markup language, doesn't have data structures. Neither does CSS, or SVG. JSON is a serialisation format. [There is something called Set in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ds-set.php) and there are other data structures mentioned but I've no idea where these come from. Haven't worked with PHP for almost a decade, so I don't know what `Ds\Set` is supposed to be.

Comment: Right. My point was only that not all of us who use javascript are from a programming background. Some of us are from a web / media background. Thus, we don't know about established data structures (in Javascript, PHP or anything else), until we learn about them.